# Insert records from output 1 to every record of output 2 from the same XML file in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis

I am using an XML document as a source in SSIS as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Doc>
  <Header>
    <ShipmentCode>ABC-EFG-123</ShipmentCode>
    <TruckCode>TRUCK-01</TruckCode>
    <TotalNumberOfPallets>3</TotalNumberOfPallets>
  </Header>  
  <Pallet>
    <SSCC>0012345</SSCC>
    <ScannedDate>1/1/2017</ScannedDate>
  </Pallet>
  <Pallet>
    <SSCC>0012346</SSCC>
    <ScannedDate>1/1/2017</ScannedDate>
  </Pallet>
  <Pallet>
    <SSCC>0012347</SSCC>
    <ScannedDate>1/1/2017</ScannedDate>
  </Pallet>
</Doc>
```

My XML source has two outputs - `Header` and `Pallet` and there is one `Header` record to many `Pallet` records, as you can see in the above XML file.

I actually want to insert records to a SQL table, but include some of the Header information along with the Pallet information as I insert. 
So the insert might include:

`ShipmentCode: ABC-EFG-123, SSCC: 0012345` - Insert record one
`ShipmentCode: ABC-EFG-123, SSCC: 001234n` - Insert record *n*

I've seen people using a Merge Join - but then I must take care of sorting? Is this example basic enough that wouldn't be a problem?

OR

I've seen people talking about using an XML task to transform the XML using XSLT. Is that the correct way to do this?  If yes, how do I figure out the XSLT syntax?

Comment: Can the file contain many headers?  If so, can you provide an example please?

Comment: At the moment it seems that there is no way to connect a `Pallet` to a `Header` in the source XML that you supplied. Perhaps when you created this sample XML you didn't accurately recreate some details?